# Django vote button with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have this url:

```
(r'^oyla/(\d+)/$', oyla),
```

I have this view:

```
@login_required
def oyla(request, id):
    if request.is_ajax():
        entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=id)
        entry.points += 1
        entry.save()
        if 'HTTP_REFERER' in request.META:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I have these in html:

```
{{ ent.points }}
<a href="/oyla/{{ ent.id }}" class="oyla">Vote Up</a>
```

and this is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a.oyla").click(function(){
    var curr_elem = $(this) ;
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
        var my_div = $(curr_elem).parent().find("b");
        my_div.text(my_div.text()*1+1);     
    }); 
    return false;
});
  </script>
```

I want to run the vote up when I click "Vote Up" I want to see the points are increasing without any page refresh. It does not works. It says

```
The view baslik.views.oyla didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

What can I do to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$.ajax` with `cache` disabled. I've read that using `$.ajax` works with all browsers but `$.get` won't send the ajax header with IE. In that case `is_ajax()` isn't `True` and no `HttpResponse` object is returned. Use:

```js
$("a.oyla").click(function(){
    var $curr_elem = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $curr_elem.attr('href'),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $curr_elem.parent().find("b").text(my_div.text()*1+1);  
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```